# Partially Curried Functions in Association List (Maps)

Tags: haskell

So I want to build a function table using association list (or maps). I did some simple tests and found the following: fully curried functions work fine but partially curried functions cannot be stored in an association list. Here is the code that works fine:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

func1 :: IO ()
func1 = putStrLn "1"

func2 :: IO ()
func2 = putStrLn "2"

funcTable = [ (1, func1)
            , (2, func2)]

callFunc :: Int -> IO ()
callFunc i = do
  let justFunc = lookup i funcTable
  case justFunc of
  Just func -> func
  Nothing -> putStrLn "Wrong!"

main = do
  callFunc 1
  callFunc 2
  callFunc 3
```

However, the following code won't compile:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

func1 :: IO ()
func1 = putStrLn "1"

func2 :: String -> IO ()
func2 s = putStrLn s

funcTable = [ (1, func1)
            , (2, func2)]

callFunc :: Int -> IO ()
callFunc i = do
  let justFunc = lookup i funcTable
  case justFunc of
    Just func1 -> func1
    Just func2 -> func2 "OK"
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Wrong!"

main = do
  callFunc 1
  callFunc 2
  callFunc 3
```

The only change I made in the code that does not compile is that I changed func2 to a partially curried function. Any trick to make it work?

Comment: The problem is not that "partially curried" functions can not be stored in a "associative" list. The problem is that the two functions do not have the same type. Furthermore in the `case`, `Just func1` will not check if the function is indeed `func1`, in this case `func1` is a *local variable*.

Comment: If your `callFunc` function has to know about all functions anyway, what's the point of keeping the dictionary?

Comment: Try to write the type for `funcTable`. You will discover that it is ill typed.

Comment: ok I see. so ghc goes down very deep in verifying lists are homogeneous!

Comment: Yes. Since everything has to have a type. So it derives that the type is `[(Int,?)]` and it can not resolve `?` since the first is a `String -> IO()` while the other is an `IO ()`. Furthermore what should the result type of `lookup` look like?

Comment: "Any trick to make it work?" - Change `func1` to `func1 :: x -> IO(); func1 _ = putStrLn "1"`. (Aside - this is a very obvious type error, making it easy to spot for commenters/potential answeres, but in general, your question should include the error, verbatim, as produced by the compiler)

Comment: *"However, the following code won't compile"*. Always add your error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with applying values to functions. The problem is that both values have different types. What would be the type of `[(1,func1),(2,func2)]`? `[(Int,IO ())]`? `[(Int, String -> IO ())]`? Both are wrong.

The simplest solution is to wrap your values of different types into a new one.

```
data Action 
  = SimpleAction (IO ())
  | StringAction (String -> IO ())

table :: [(Int, Action)]
table = [(1, SimpleAction func1), (2, StringAction func2)]

callFunc :: Int -> IO ()
callFunc i = case lookup i table of
  Just (SimpleAction action) -> action
  Just (StringAction action) -> action "OK"
  Nothing -> error "wrong"
```

Note that `func1` is not a function by the way.